# Please help me open it "xampp"

Tags: software-installation

It's opened it with pypar.I don't want this.How can i open without pypar

[image]

Comment: see https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html I myself would use command line for this.

Comment: The tiny text on the picture is hard to read.  I could give you the exact command to type if you had used text instead of a picture.  If you edit your question and add the name of the file you want to open to your question it'll make it easier to read.  The `Stackexchange ` engine would also automatically present you with related links that you could review showing you possible resolutions while you type.  It appears to be a `*.run` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `*.run` file.  The file is an executionable installer.  You can run this file by first setting the execution bit, then run it from the a terminal command prompt.

You can get to a terminal command prompt by typing `terminal` in the Ubuntu Button.  Then click on Terminal.

Run this on the file (for instance installer-file.bin):

```
$ chmod +x installer-file.bin
$ sudo ./installer-file.bin
```

Don't type the "$" as part of the command.  The `$` sympbol is showing how your command prompt look.  The `sudo` is to run the command in the elevated mode to install the package `system-wide`.